# How to get back an older version of my project in Eclipse Luna?

Tags: eclipse, revert, eclipse-luna

I'm working on a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse Luna.
I modified several file and the project doesn't run anymore and I don't know all the modifications I done.
Is there a way to revert to an older version of my project?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the individual files and select 'Replace With > Local History' to see the history that Eclipse has.

Eclipse only keeps history for a limited period. See 'Preferences > General > Workspace > Local History' for the configuration for this.

Although this history is useful it is not really a substitute for using a proper source control system such as SVN or Git which can be used to retain all versions of your code.